# Java PDFBox merge 4 pages to a single page

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm working on a snippet of Java Code to merge 4 PDFs (Din A4) to a single page (4x DinA6 on DinA4) and print that out. I got that printing part up and running, but I'm struggeling to merge the pages.

My first attempts were with python and quite easy:

```
scale = 0.5
out.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(firstPage, scale, 0, (firstPage.mediaBox.getHeight() / 2))
out.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(secondPage, scale, (firstPage.mediaBox.getWidth() / 2), (firstPage.mediaBox.getHeight() / 2))
out.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(thrdPage, scale, 0, 0)
out.mergeScaledTranslatedPage(fourthPage, scale , (firstPage.mediaBox.getWidth() / 2), 0)
```

Is there something that can compete with the magic of mergeScaledTranslatedPage in Java? I'm using PDFBox 2.

Comment: What exactly is `out`? I'm not actively aware of a PDFBox method `mergeScaledTranslatedPage`...

Comment: Ouh I'm sorry, my example is written in Python and uses PyPDF. I'm looking for a snippet of Java Code that achieves the same result.